# Why is only the first value inserted in the database using pdo and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm breaking my head over this for over a week now. When I POST an id and a string to this php file, then only the id is recorded into the database but the other value not. Has anyone a clue why this is happening?

I get no errors. If I know then I hopefully can solve `UPDATE` with too.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mastertest;charset=utf8', 'root', '', 
array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
try { 
    $nr = (isset($_POST['nr']) ? $_POST['nr'] : '');  
    $news = (isset($_POST['news']) ? $_POST['news'] : '');
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO `test` (`id`, `flashnews`) VALUES (:nr, :news)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':nr', $_POST['nr']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':news', $_POST['news']);
    if($stmt->execute()) { echo "Success!"; } else { echo "Failure!"; };
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Not updated: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Don't post the value of `var_dump($_POST);`. It's totally not the only possible variable that's of interest here, seeing it just represents the input you're having problems with. Also, do you really write code that's so randomly indented (or - not indented)?

Comment: So, you're doing `$stmt->execute()` 3 times. Cool.

Comment: Why not `prepare` once, and then `execute(array(':nr' => $_POST['nr'], ...))`  as many times as necessary?

Comment: @ u_mulder ah yeah i see what you mean. So i removed the 2 that were to much. Ok now i need to understand what N.B. exactly means with his comment. So in fact i only need 1 row and 2 colums. A very tiny DB. If i finnaly understand it all. Then i can continue a little step to updating it.

Comment: You are wondering why `flashnews` is not being populated, but you never, ever check if there's anything in `$_POST['news']`. What is the logical conclusion? You are inserting value of `$_POST['news']` and it's blank. There, if you can't conclude what's wrong from this comment or how to proceed with debugging, then you might not be cut out for this kind of work.

Comment: @jjsjjs I believe he's pulling your leg, I would definitely like to see what `var_dump($_POST)` displays.

Comment: Ha yes thank you. I get this returned : array(2) { ["nr"]=> &string(10) "6news=dfgf" ["news"]=> &NULL } yes i see where it goes wrong, in posting it, the nr is in the news= part, ok i will see if i can fix that. and that's why only the nr is recorded because that's an INT as in the DB

Comment: Ok found it what caused it, i forgot to send an & sign in front of news=, so my string send to the php file is now id=5&news=good news!  i could have known this because my mysql script did work correct, i just forgot. No hard feelings @N.B. you just got me thinking a bit more :) and thanks Josh Rumbut

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it on your own, no hard feelings at all :)